# Extract Multiple Tables in a word file to an Excel File using Python

Tags: python

I have a Microsoft Word file which contains multiple tables. Word file has 8 pages. In each page, there's a table. I want to extract the tables in that word file into a single excel file. As I'm new to python, can anyone help me with it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no [tag:python] in this question.

Comment: See [ask], and what is on topic in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score -1):

fisrt you need to extract the tables from the word documnet using pdfparser in python then convert the tables into csv file